# GetStream Chat API to open thread

Tags: getstream-io

Using Stream Chat React library on desktop https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react

Use case - clicking on web push notification should open specific thread.

How to programmatically open specific thread by parent message id?

Looked into `openThread` and `handleOpenThread` props but not exactly what needed.

Comment: Are you looking for a feature that jumps to a specific point in a channel when clicked on?

Comment: That would be nice but also open specific thread programmatically. Ideally make it deep linkable like Slack ( routing part outside of the scope of this question of course )

Comment: Unfortunately this feature does not exist in Stream Chat right now

Comment: Thanks, do you think this feature will be available in future?

Comment: We'd love it to be ready in Q2 of this year. It's a hot feature but a big lift for our team. Here are some of the features we're looking forward to implementing https://getstream.io/blog/stream-in-2020/

Comment: Hi there! Any updates on this? I think I'm looking for a similar feature: make the react UI component to scroll to a specific message ID programmatically.